# Apple Push Notification with PHP, iphone does not recieve, what does possibility cause this happen?

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

here, is my coding on linux server.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(); 
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns-prod.pem'); 
$apnsConnection = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx); 

$deviceToken = "XXXX";  //no space
$message = "A new question has been posted";

$body = array();
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
$badge = 1;
$sound = 1;

if($badge)
{$body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;}

if($sound)
{$body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;}

$payload = json_encode($body);
$msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
echo $payload;

fwrite($apnsConnection, $msg);
fclose($apnsConnection);
```

Comment: Maybe you can learn something from: http://www.easyapns.com/

Comment: Possibly this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293155/apple-push-notification-service-apns-notifications-not-arriving

Answer (score 1):

It happens, if your hosting server doesn't open the port:2195 or 2196.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem. I guess Apple is not sending the push for some error.
So I solved it like this:
When the iPhone receives the push it goes back to the server and updates the GetPush column in the table.
As long (or maybe three times) as this GetPush column is not set the server will ask the Apple server to send the push.